# Convert a unified diff to an array of vscode.TextEdit objects

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have a formatting tool which produces a unified diff. I want to write a VSCode formatter for it. I am using a JavaScript package to parse the diff into something I can consume in JavaScript.

The code I have so far is the following:

```js
const edits: vscode.TextEdit[] = [];
const diff = require("parse-diff")(unfiedDiff);
for (const chunk of diff.chunks) {
  for (const change of chunk.changes) {
    switch (change.type) {
      case "add": {
        const position = new vscode.Position(change.ln - 1, 0);

        edits.push(vscode.TextEdit.insert(position, `${change.content.substring(1)}${eol}`));
        break;
      }
      case "del": {
        const start = new vscode.Position(change.ln - 1, 0);
        const end = start.translate(1);
        const range = new vscode.Range(start, end);

        edits.push(vscode.TextEdit.delete(range));
        break;
      }
      case "normal":
        if (change.ln1 === change.ln2) continue;

        const delStart = new vscode.Position(change.ln1 - 1, 0);
        const delEnd = delStart.translate(1);
        const delRange = new vscode.Range(delStart, delEnd);

        edits.push(vscode.TextEdit.delete(delRange));

        const insPosition = new vscode.Position(change.ln2 - 1, 0);

        edits.push(vscode.TextEdit.insert(insPosition, `${change.content.substring(1)}${eol}`));
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

It almost works, but I am missing something. Here is a reproducer:

```c
static int
func(void) {
    while (1) {
    finish:
        if (1)
            break;
    }
}
```

```
--- ./test.c    2023-12-14 14:31:07.437254284 -0600
+++ pgdiff4sph4 2023-12-14 14:31:13.082246812 -0600
@@ -1,7 +1,9 @@
 static int
-func(void) {
-       while (1) {
-       finish:
+func(void)
+{
+       while (1)
+       {
+finish:
                if (1)
                        break;
        }
```

After running my code through the algorithm, I get the following:

```c
static int
func(void)
{
    while (1)
    {
finish:
        if (1)
            break;
} // <-- This bracket should exist two lines lower.
    }
```

It is unclear where I am going wrong.

Comment: It's almost like I need to shift everything I didn't touch down two lines (9 - 7). This is surprisingly difficult.

Comment: just to be clear, how exactly are you applying the edits? `DocumentFormattingEditProvider`? `DocumentRangeFormattingEditProvider`? `OnTypeFormattingEditProvider`? `WorkspaceEdit`?

Comment: I wonder if the add/insert and delete starting at the same position has anything to do with the problem? what do you see if you just comment out the delete logic temporarily? and if you comment out the add logic temporarily? do the add and delete go in the right place if you do them separately?

Comment: also, doesn't normal mean you don't need to do anything? https://github.com/sergeyt/parse-diff/blob/a916dbccacdf9d55bd57726ab1bd05c55449efee/parse.js#L15 and... can't you handle each chunk as a single replace edit?

Comment: Sorry, I am using `DocumentFormattingEditProvider`. I will update the post to include that information.

Comment: Here is what I get when I comment out the delete (and normal) portions of code:

```
static void
func(void)
func(void) {
{
 while (1) {
 while (1)
 finish:
 {
  if (1)
finish:
   break;
 }
}
```

Here is what I get when I comment out add and uncomment delete:

```
static void
  if (1)
   break;
 }
}
```

These look correct.

Comment: Hmm. What would be the best way to share it? Anyway, If I don't have the normal logic, my more complicated diffs work less well. But I think you are onto something about one giant replace for a particular chunk. I am thinking about this too granularly, I think.